# How to debug with VSCODE for mac (C language)

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to launch the debugger but it doesn't work.
Do you have any idea how to make it work ?

This is the error i get :

[image: This is the error I get]

This is my code. (very simple).

[image]

This is my launch.json file.

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch (lldb)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false
        }
    ]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the posted code will cause the compiler to output 3 warning messages.  Two(2) about unused parameters in the signature for `main()`   one(1) for the variable: `entier` about a local variable being set but never used.   There is not much reason to start debugging a program that does not cleanly compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration above does not contain the debugger to use. For macOS you would most likely use `lldb`. To make VSCode aware of your wish to use `lldb` you have to set

```
"MIMode": "lldb"
```

You can also use a custom path to `lldb` like so:

```
"miDebuggerPath": "/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/lldb"
```

More more information see [VSCode: Configuring C/C++ debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference)